# Why do the graphs of $\tan(x+a)$ and $\tan(x-a)$ line up when $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ if the period of $\tan(x)$ is $\pi$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Why do the graphs of $\tan(x+a)$ and $\tan(x-a)$ line up when $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ if the period of $\tan(x)$ is $\pi$?

I graphed $\tan(x+a)$ and $\tan(x-a)$ in desmos (link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rxppnlgkz4) and the graphs first line up when $$a=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
shouldn't the graphs only line up when $a$ is multiple of $\pi$ in other words when $a=\pi*n$ where $n\in W$

Comment: Note that the difference between $x+\pi/2$ and $x-\pi/2$ is $\pi$, **not** $\pi/2$.

Comment: If you've shifted one graph $\pi/2$ to the left, and the other $\pi/2$ to the right, then the relative shift between them is $\pi$.

Comment: Say $t=x-\frac\pi2$. Then $\tan(x-\frac\pi2)=\tan(t)=\tan(t+\pi)=\tan(x+\frac\pi2)$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the difference between the inputs of $\tan(x+\pi/2)$ and $\tan(x-\pi/2)$ is a distance of $\pi$. More generally,

$$\tan \left( x + \frac \pi 2 \right) 
= \tan \left( x + \frac \pi 2 + n \pi \right) 
= \tan \left( x + \frac{2n+1}{2} \pi \right)$$

for any integer $n$. Even more generally, if $f$ has a period of $p$, then

$$f(x) = f(x+np)$$

for any integer $n$. This holds true even if you replace $x$ with $x+a$ for some real number $a$.

Since $\tan(x)$ has a period of $\pi$, the overlap of the graphs is thus entirely natural and to be expected.

---

*Answering like this to ensure that the question does not end up in the "unanswered" queue, but making Community Wiki since I have nothing further to offer.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the trigonometry, Luke.
$$
\tan (x\pm a)={\sin(x\pm a)\over \cos(x\pm a)}={\sin x\cos a\pm\sin a\cos x\over \cos x\cos a\mp\sin x\sin a}
$$
Now $\cos\pm\pi/2=0$ and the $\sin a$ term cancels, so
$$
\tan (x\pm\pi/2)=-{\cos x\over \sin x}.
$$